# Change select dropdown based on first select dropdown?

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to change the second select dropdown based on whether the first selected option contains an (m) or (ft).

My form HTML search is as follows:

```
<form id="search" action="/property_search" method="get" class="clearfix">
        <select name="sqsize" id="sqsize" class="sqsize">
            <option value="">sq.ft/sq.m:</option>
            <option value="233.52m">233.52m</option>
            <option value="233.52m">233.52m</option>
            <option value="467.04m">467.04m</option>
            <option value="2,513ft">2,513ft</option>
            <option value="2,513ft">2,513ft</option>
            <option value="5,026ft">5,026ft</option>
        </select>

        <select name="sqsizemin" id="sqsizemin" class="sqsizemin">
            <option value="">Size Min:</option>
        </select>

        <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
```

My Jquery is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('#sqsize').change(function () {
var options = '';
if($(this).val() == 'm') {
    options = '<option value=""></option>';
}
else if ($(this).val() == 'ft') {
    options = '<option value="6">6</option>';
}
    $('#sqsizemin').html(options);
});
    $('#sqsize').trigger('change');
});
```

Comment: what is not working? did you notice your double closed `</select>` ?

Comment: I have edited my question. My question has been answered below. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this(using `indexOf`):

```
$(function(){
$("#sqsize").change(function(){
    var options = '';
    if($(this).val().indexOf('m') > -1) {
        options = '<option value="">mm</option>';
    }
    else if ($(this).val().indexOf('ft') > -1) {
        options = '<option value="6">6</option>';
    }
    $('#sqsizemin').html(options);        
});
});
```

#### Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/b0w61quf/

Comment: Legend! Works a treat thanks very much for your answer. It is exactly what I am after.

Comment: @Craig, i'm glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/kc5qqtco/

```
$(function(){

    $('#sqsize').change(function () {

        if($(this).val().match(/m/g)) {

            $('<option value=""></option>').appendTo('#sqsizemin');
        }
        else if ($(this).val().match(/ft/g)) {

            $('<option value="6">6</option>').appendTo('#sqsizemin');

        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `indexOf` will get you a working solution.

See the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5zcc6bkk/2/)